# How to force wildfly-8.2.1.Final to load .class from a directory rather than war?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, classloader, wildfly-8, war-filedeployment

I want load .class file from a given directory so, i put compiled file inside the directory /opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/packagename/ and also server load the classes from the same directory rather than war(WEB-INF/classes/packagename/).

Comment: So you want the class to be loaded from `/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/packagename/` rather than `WEB-INF/classes/packagename/`?

Comment: @Konrad Botor, Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this method myself, but you must:

1. Move `/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/packagename/` to
   `/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/custom-classes/main/packagename/`
2. Add file `module.xml` to
   `/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/custom-classes/main/`
3. Add file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to your war.
4. Undeploy the war, restart the server and then redeploy the war.

Content of `module.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="custom-classes">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="."/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Contents of `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
    <deployment>  
         <dependencies>  
              <module name="custom-classes" />    
        </dependencies>  
    </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Edit: If you want to add jars as well as non-jared classes to your module you must not only copy jars to `/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/custom-classes/main/`, but also list jars in `module.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="custom-classes">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="."/>
            <resource-root path="dependency1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="dependency2.jar"/>
            <!-- and so on for other jars -->
        </resources>
    </module>
```

Resources:

- [Class Loading in WildFly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)
- [How to write jboss-deployment-structure.xml](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/202130)
- [How to ad directory to JBoss classpath](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/219956)

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am getting an error Failed to define class com.demo.project.controller.LoginController in Module "custom-classes:main" from local module loader  (finder: local module finder (roots: /opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules,/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base)): java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/demo/project/controller/LoginController (Module "custom-classes:main" from local module loader (finder: local module finder (roots: /opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules,/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base)))

Comment: As described in `Class Loading in WildFly` classes from modules are loaded before classes from war, so if the class(es) placed inside the module depend on class(es) inside the war the module won't load

Comment: i have put all dependencies (jar) inside modules(/opt/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/modules/custom-classes/main/)but i got the same error, can you please suggest?